# Trying to build VLC for Unity3D

Tags: debian, vlc, libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

I have been trying to get the VLC plugin for Unity3D to build.  It is found here: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/blob/master/README.md

I am trying to do this on Debian 10 (buster).

The first instruction was to: Download and install https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw on latest Debian (WSL or otherwise). Add it to path.

I believe I have done that part successfully.

Next is to: Download VLC nightly build and adjust if need be vlc-4.0.0-dev/sdk/lib path to LDFLAGS in Common.mk

This is where my issue is. I've done the snap install of the nightly build, I've downloaded the source with a -dev in name from here: https://nightlies.videolan.org/build/source/

I've also tried to use the master-daily PPA.

But I still cannot find any vlc-4.0.0-dev/sdk/lib path.

I have tried to set the LDFLAGS to some of the vlc lib folders I have, but every time I build I get this error:

```
lld: error: unable to find library -lvlc
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

My end goal, if I can get this VLC plugin working, is to stream one of my Unity3D virtual cameras to a viewer on the network via rtsp.

Comment: I don't think you wanted to use the tag for the **game engine [Unity3D](https://www.unity3d.com)** here.. Please read the tag description carefully when tagging your question.

Comment: Then why not simply do `apt install vlc`..?

Comment: Then in general Linux specific questions should rather  go to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com)

Comment: I apologize for the incorrect tag and if I've posted in the wrong area.  I did do apt install vlc.  In the instructions is specifies changing the LDFLAG to a vlc-4.0.0-dev/sdk/lib path.  After installing vlc several ways I still cannot find any vlc-4.0.0-dev/sdk/lib path.  I don't know if I'm looking in the wrong area or if a vlc nightly has to be built in a certain way to get a sdk/lib folder. Thanks again.

Comment: Also for future reference, I have a question about tagging, as whole purpose of doing this vlc build was to create a .dll needed to use the vlc Unity3D plugin why wasn't the Unity3D tag valid, thanks.

Comment: well to me it sounded more like you ment the Unity Desktop environment of Ubuntu. From your question it wasn't clear to me that you want to use this as a plugin in Unity3D .. also .. what speaks against the existing [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) and/or [Pro Audio Player](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/audio/pro-audio-player-34549) ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for the confusion, I didn't realize there was a desktop environment for Ubuntu called Unity.  So my goal, if I can get this VLC plugin working, is to stream one of my virtual cameras to a viewer on the network. (via rtsp I believe, which I think this plugin can do). I appreciate your help, but I don't believe those will help.  When I searched for Unity3d and rtsp, this vlc plugin seemed to be the best thing to try.

Comment: If rtsp is not a must, there is a solution with WebSocket, using FMETP STREAM.
https://youtu.be/2oxDz_wsDkE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this plugin is currently Windows-only, I'm assuming you are targeting Windows.

Download a nightly from https://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win64-llvm/last/

You will find the libs at `vlc-4.0.0-{date}-dev-win64.7z\vlc-4.0.0-dev\sdk\lib\`

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Downloading the nightly from your link and using that path worked.

Comment: mtz,  Have you successfully built/gathered all the pieces for this plugin?  I'm currently stuck trying to figure out where to get the LibVLCSharp.dll file from. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/unity/scripts/build-unity-windows.sh from the unity branch, but latest might not work as there has been some changes which might break windows. Will be more stable in a few weeks, or revert what doesnt work

Comment: Thank you again mtz!  Was the build-unity-windows.sh supposed to be run on linux or windows?  I tried running on debian after installing dotnet, but I was getting errors, something like Microsoft.WinFX.props not found.

I then ran the command in the script in a windows cmd window and I believe it worked.  I got a download timeout error but it said build successful and it created the LibVLCSharp.dll.

I imported everything into Unity but when I try the sample I get EntryPointNotFoundException: libvlc_unity_media_player_new.  Is this part of the issues you were talking about?

Comment: In unity the exception is happening at the line _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC)